# How to Create Python Macros in DBT for External API Calls and JDBC Connections

Tags: azure, dbt, azure-monitor

I'm working on a data transformation project using DBT (Data Build Tool), and I'd like to create Python macros in DBT that can make external API calls and JDBC connections to interact with an Azure Monitor instance. I'm unsure about the best approach to achieve this integration.

Specifically, I have the following requirements:

Create Python macros in my DBT project.
Inside these macros, make HTTP requests to external APIs (e.g., Azure Monitor API).
Establish JDBC connections to external data sources.
Trigger these macros as part of my DBT workflow.
I have experience with DBT and Python, but I'm unsure how to structure these macros and integrate them into my DBT project effectively.**strong text**

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a request for code, not for comments and suggested fixes, and StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0):

Install DBT by running the `pip install dbt` command and **Initialize a DBT Project:**

- In my terminal, I ran the `dbt init my_dbt_project` command to create a new DBT project.

  This command generated a directory structure for my project, including `models`, `data`, and `macros` directories, among others. It also created a `dbt_project.yml` file.

[image]

**Configure My DBT Project**

- I opened the `dbt_project.yml` file and customized it according to my project's needs. I set the `name` field to the name of my project.
- I also configured my database connection in the `profiles.yml` file. For example, for a PostgreSQL connection, my configuration looked like this:

**yamlCopy code:**

```
my_postgres_db:
  target: dev
  outputs:
    dev:
      type: postgres
      host: localhost
      port: 5432
      user: your_username
      pass: your_password
      dbname: your_database_name
```

[image]

I replaced `your_username`, `your_password`, and `your_database_name` with my actual database credentials.

**Create Python Macros for API Calls**

- Inside the `macros` directory, I created a Python file named `api_macros.py`. Here's the content of the file:

```
# macros/api_macros.py
import requests

def call_azure_monitor_api(api_url, api_key):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {api_key}',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
    response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        raise Exception(f"API call failed with status code {response.status_code}")
```

- In my DBT models where I want to use these macros, I called them in the `pre-hook` or `post-hook` sections of the model configurations.

[image]

**Create DBT Models**

- To create a DBT model, I ran the `dbt seed my_source_data`  command.

  This command generated a sample CSV file (`data/my_source_data.csv`) and a corresponding DBT model file (`models/my_source_data.sql`).
- In the model file (`models/my_source_data.sql`), I defined my SQL transformations to transform source data into the desired format.

**Run DBT Commands**

- To execute the transformations defined in my DBT models, I used the following command `dbt run` .

[image]

DBT connected to my specified database using the credentials in `profiles.yml`, executed the SQL transformations, and created tables or views in my target database.

Comment: As of dbt-core 1.5.8 this does not work. Firstly, there's a typo: correct parameter name to specify a pre-hook in {{config()}} block is pre_hook, not pre-hook. Secondly, for me this gives an error: Non-query expression encountered in illegal context